# SQL Server monitoring of excution time for a specific query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, monitoring

In our environment we use SQL Server 2014, Grafana, InfluxDB for metrics storage and Telegraf for metrics collection. And it will be very useful to see the history of each query execution time. We need a list of all queries from a query plan in SQL Server and related to it a graph of its execution duration. Is there any complete solutions? Or we need implement it ourself?

Comment: Sounds like you should check out my super duper favorite db tool. SentryOne Plan Explorer. It's free and sounds like it has exactly what you need (metrics, analysis of plans). Here's the link: https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer

Comment: @JacobH looks very interesting and promising. Does it show reasons of query performance degradations? (In my case I think it is blocking by other queries)

Comment: I haven't used that feature, but on the page it does say that you can use to troubleshoot deadlocks.

Comment: Is upgrading an option? If so, 2016 comes with the Query Store which does what you want natively. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatform/2017/01/31/query-store-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/. Maybe this is the info you need to convice the boss to make that upgrade? 
SQL Server updates are very well tested now, there's almost no reason not to unless you have old software integrating with SQL Server that will break.